# Django - saving partially filled form to prevent data loss

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a form which takes quite a long time for the user to fill. I would like to set up a feature (some AJAX) which saves the currently filled values every N seconds so that the user does not lose their data in case of connection problems/misclick/internal server error.

Sure, I can do this on my own by saving the user and filled values in some serialized form (say JSON) into a manually created table in the database. But I wonder, can Django do this for me?

I hope it makes sense at least a bit and thanks in advance for your ideas!

Comment: Why not a cookie to store on the user's local storage which can be used for auto fill

Comment: that is definitely an option, but I would like to persist the data even in case the user opens another browser or wants to finish filling the form eg. on their mobile phone, therefore I would prefer a server-side solution for this

Comment: I don't think django has but as you said jQuery will do the job https://stackoverflow.com/a/13477029/7887883

Comment: very useful link, thank you

Comment: One approach I've used, which may or may not make sense for you, is to split the form in sections and have them be saved individually. Like the [form wizard](https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html) that used to be part of Django, which can store partial information on a session or cookie.